# "main.exe" Has Crashed Error

Tags: c++

I am having a simple error. The project is to create a skeleton of a basic menu. The new command just counts from 1 to an integer entered by the user. Before I continue, I have posted a link to the pastebin that holds my .cpp file:
http://pastebin.com/pAi9EiEi

The rest of the program runs and works. However, the error is simple. It is crashing as soon as I type in any of the commands. After running error checks, I have found the error is not the while but the if statements. The error is on the lines similar to this:

```
if (stricmp(strstr(newCommand, cmd2), newCommand) == 0)
```

What this line is supposed to do, is copy what is in cmd2 and put it in newCommand then comparing it without caps sensitivity to:

```
char newCommand[] = "new";
```

Comment: You might [Open letter to students](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166/64132) useful.

Comment: are you forbidden from using std::string? because if it's allowed, the code just gets so much simpler

Comment: @KateGregory Except that he wants to do a case-insensitive compare :)

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply I figured it out and fixed a few other bugs in the code. I have simplified it down as well, to make it easier to add on to with the next part in this project. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"What this line is supposed to do, is copy what is in cmd2 and put it in newCommand then comparing it without caps sensitivity to:"

If the code did this, it would be comparing the former contents of `cmd2` to itself, wouldn't it?

```
copy cmd2 -> newCommand
is cmd2 == newCommand?
```

If the user typed "open", then on the first iteration of your loop it would copy "open" into "newCommand" and you would no-longer have the string "new" anywhere in your program.

`strstr` searches the first string for an occurrence of the second.

```
strstr("hello world", "world"); // returns pointer to 'world' in 'hello world'
strstr("biscuit", "new");  // returns NULL to indicate new doesn't occur in 'biscuit'
```

Surely what you actually want to do is simply:

```
if (stricmp(newCommand, cmd2) == 0) {
    // match
}
```

Incidentally, if you *did* want to copy "cmd2" into "newCommand", you would want to use `strcpy(destinationStr, sourceStr)`;

```
strcpy(newCommand, cmd2);
```

Answer (score 2):

that line doesn't do what you think it does

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/

it searches for the occurence of cmd2 in newcommand and returns a pointer to it (null if not found) and unless I'm mistaken passing a null in stricmp is undefined behavior

you just want a plain stricmp and you do away with the copy